# Sum multiple values for same key in lists using python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
(151258350, 2464)
(151258350, 56)
(151262958, 56)
(151258350, 56)
(151262958, 112)
(151262958, 112)
(151259627, 56)
(151262958, 112)
(151262958, 56)
```

And I want a result that looks like this:

```
151259627 56
151262958 448
151258350 2576
```

And here's my code:

```
for key, vals in d.items():
    tempList.append((key, reduce(add, vals)))
```

here, d is the list with the key-value pair. tempList is the List in which the values will be appended after summing them by key. and add is a fuction:

```
def add(x, y): return x+y
```

If this question has already been asked, please point me there as I was unsuccessful in finding it myself.

Comment: What is `d`? What is `tempList`? What is `add`? What is the question?

Comment: `d.items()` ? Seems like you have a dictionary, but you say you have a list?

Comment: @juanchopanza - added clarification for your question. Thanks for stopping by this trivial question and leaving your comments. They're asked by those who are still beginners in a scripting language.

Comment: @Nir Being a beginner in a programming language is not a problem. It is about asking clear, concise questions without people having to second-guess you.

Comment: @juanchopanza, thanks for the tip. That was bonus learning :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num_list = [(151258350, 2464),
(151258350, 56),
(151262958, 56),
(151258350, 56),
(151262958, 112),
(151262958, 112),
(151259627, 56),
(151262958, 112),
(151262958,56)]
num_dict = {}
for t in num_list:
    if t[0] in num_dict:
        num_dict[t[0]] = num_dict[t[0]]+t[1]
    else:
        num_dict[t[0]] = t[1]

for key,value in num_dict.items():
    print "%d %d" %(key,value)
```

Comment: Don’t do `dict.get(key)` to check if a key exists in a dictionary. Use `key in dict`.

Comment: What is the advantage of `key in dict` over `dict.get`?

Comment: `dict.get(key)` returns the *value* (`dict[key]`) if the key exists, or `None` as the fallback value if the key does not exist. It does not actually check if the key exists in the dictionary. For example, with a dictionary `d = { 'foo': None, 'bar': 0 }`, neither of those keys will be reported as existing in the dictionary (because `d['foo']` is `None`, and `d['foo']` returns a false-ish value).

Comment: Could you paste your `num_list`?

Answer (score 13):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> l = [(151258350, 2464),
(151258350, 56),
(151262958, 56),
(151258350, 56),
(151262958, 112),
(151262958, 112),
(151259627, 56),
(151262958, 112),
(151262958, 56)]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for k, v in l:
        c[k] += v

>>> c
Counter({151258350: 2576, 151262958: 448, 151259627: 56})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Counter [counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```
from collections import Counter

cnt=Counter()
for key,value in l:
    cnt[key] += value

print cnt
```

> part 2

if you found "Animesh's" answer interesting, you can try it in a simpler way: this will not need any imports. Without using .get()

```
l = [(151258350, 2464),                                                     
   (151258350, 56),
   (151262958, 56),
   (151258350, 56),
   (151262958, 112),
   (151262958, 112),
   (151259627, 56),
   (151262958, 112),
   (151262958, 56)]

count={}
for k,v in l:
     if k in count:
         count[k] += v
     else:
         count[k]=v
print count
```

Comment: Keys in dictionaries are by design unique, so doing `+=` on `cnt[key]` is not necessary because the key will not exist yet if you iterate over the dictionary `d`. And if you have a dictionary as a base, you can just do `Counter(d)` to create a counter from it. But since OP has multiple identical “keys”, I don’t believe that they have a dictionary.

Comment: @poke i have edited them now... but now it looks like your code....thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
result = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in source:
    result[key] += value

# if you really want result as a list of tuples
rslt = list(result.items())
```

If your `source` is actually a dict (not a list of tuples as you descirbed it in the question), replace `for key, value in source:` with `for key, value in source.iteritems():`

Comment: `source` cannot be a dictionary because OP has multiple identical keys—in dictionaries, the key would be unique.

Comment: Other than that note, the answer is perfectly fine though, so I don’t know why this is being downvoted…

Comment: @poke it's a bit unclear from the question, as the code OP had clearly used `items`, which is present on dicts, but not on lists... And question said nothing about `AttributeError` that it would cause. So I included both approaches. As of downvote - probably someone haven't read the answer thoughtfully :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple one-liner without importing any library:

```
r = dict(set((a, sum(y for x, y in t if x == a)) for a, b in t))
```